# Disable initial focus on TextBox in a Grid

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10

I have a Flyout with this body:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
      DataContext="{Binding}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBox x:Uid="LocationSearchBox"  
             PlaceholderText="Blah"
             Grid.Row="0"
             TabIndex="1"
             Text="{Binding SearchQuery, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <ListView x:Name="SuggestionsList" ItemsSource="{Binding Suggestions}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLocation, Mode=TwoWay}"
              TabIndex="0"
              Margin="10,20,0,0"
              Grid.Row="2">
    </ListView> 
</Grid>
```

On the initial load textbox is selected and I need it to be out of focus.
Changing TabIndex does not help and tagging the textbox with TabStop="False" will prevent editing the text box. 
Any idea how I can disable the initial focus?

Comment: I have a feeling that you are using an older version of Windows 10 SDK. The current `PlaceholderText` has a lower-case `holder` and it's visible as long as the user hasn't typed in anything into the `TextBox`. In other words, even when the `TextBox` is focused, you should still see that `Blah` text.

Comment: That was a typo(bug), I still have problem with it being selected for other requirements. I'll edit the post. Thanks for pointing that out.